# Need to have the embedded DocuSign tool (Note: should come to our website once done with the editing ) for the our website

Tags: docusignapi

Need to  have the embedded DocuSign tool (Note: should come to our website once done with the editing ) for the our website

Comment: What is your question?  Check your tags [embedded] was neither the correct or useful tag.  The body and the title should not be identical.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are talking about implementing an embedded signing ceremony. Please have a look at our documentation [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/). Setting the redirect url as seen in steps 4 and 5 will redirect the user to your website.